# How to compile a solidity file using solc? (Version 0.8.15, node.js)

Tags: node.js, compilation, solidity

I have been trying for some time to compile the simple contract I created using solc but without success.

The contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;


contract basic {


modifier onlyOwner {
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
}

address public owner;
address public peer;

address public lastSender;
int public lastAmaunt;

constructor(address p2){
    owner=msg.sender;
    peer=p2;
}

//see the balance of the contract
function getTotalBalance () public view returns (uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}

//only owner can sent money from contract 
function sentMoneyto (uint to,uint256 _value) public onlyOwner{
        if(to==1){
            (payable(peer)).transfer(_value);
        }else{
            (payable(owner)).transfer(_value);
        }
}
//can get money from evreyone 
function getMoneyFrom() public payable{
        lastSender = msg.sender;
        lastAmaunt =int(msg.value);
}

function cangePeer(address newPeer) public onlyOwner{
    peer=newPeer;
}

}
```

Not a complex contract, its purpose is to transfer money between two accounts as a middleman.
compile file:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
 
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');
 
const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Inbox.sol': {
            content: source,
        },
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['*'],
            },
        },
    },
};
 
 
compilesFiles = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts[
    'Inbox.sol'
].Inbox;

console.log(compilesFiles);
```

When I run compile.js I get the following output ...

[my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cnVH.png)

My intention is to save the output in the file after compiling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabe its because of `solc` version, but the problem was with the below line.

before:

```
compilesFiles = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts[
'Inbox.sol'
].Inbox;
```

After:

```
compilesFiles = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts[
'Inbox.sol'
].basic;
```

Below is a working example!

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra')
 
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');
 
const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Inbox.sol': {
            content: source,
        },
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['*'],
            },
        },
    },
};

/**
 * Writes the contracts from the compiled sources into JSON files, which you will later be able to
 * use in combination with web3.
 * @param compiled - Object containing the compiled contracts.
 * @param buildPath - Path of the build folder.
 */
function writeOutput(compiled, buildPath) {
    fsExtra.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

    for (let contractFileName in compiled.contracts) {
        const contractName = contractFileName.replace('.sol', '');
        console.log('Writing: ', contractName + '.json');
        fsExtra.outputJsonSync(
            path.resolve(buildPath, contractName + '.json'),
            compiled.contracts[contractFileName].basic
        );
    }
}
 
 
compilesFiles = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
writeOutput(compilesFiles, buildPath);
```

Reference: [best reference](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/compiling-ethereum-smart-contracts-locally-0-5-2-0-5-x-ebfea0aed3a9)

Comment: @EyalItzhak You're welcome, if issue is resolved, please close the issue!